# hosting python telegram bot on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, telegram-bot

I have a `.py` file with some code to run a `telegram bot` and it works fine on my local machine but when i push my code into `heroku` it doesn't work, i mean the file is not running to receive and send messages but when i enter the bash in `heroku` and run the `.py` file manually it works fine.
I apply some changes in `Procfile` but i do not know how to tell `heroku` to run the `.py` file automatically.
I also tried to wrap my `bot` code inside a flask app and again it works perfect on local machine, but on the `heroku` the flask requests handled successfully but the bot inside the code doesn't work again.
Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask
import time
import os
import telepot
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, PickleType, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from flask.ext.heroku import Heroku

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "random string"
heroku = Heroku(app)

@app.route('/')  # the requests handled successfully!
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

# the bot code deleted to simplify

uri = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
engine = create_engine(uri)
Base = declarative_base()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    global session
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    TOKEN = 'token'

    bot = MyBot(TOKEN)  # the bot stuff here
    bot.message_loop()  # but the bot stuff just doesn't work

    # i also removed incoming 2 lines and let it be the default but has no effect 
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))  

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
    while 1:
        time.sleep(10)

    engine.dispose()
```

I checked the log from `heroku` there was no error, but the `bot` code doesn't work.
So what is the problem in the "flask wrapped" `bot` AND how can i just simply tell the `heroku` to run a python file and let it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have to put into `Procfile` such a string:

```
web: python web.py
```

Where `web.py` is the name of your script.

Also check `requirements.txt` file with all dependencies included. Look at this article [on Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip).

After deploying your code run your app and if there is error - check your Heroku logs. You can check logs at Heroku dashboard by clicking button in the right corner `More` -> `View logs`.